# Unable to do named aggregation after groupby().count()

Tags: python, pandas, count, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame with two columns. I need to group by one of the columns, then find the group with the maximum number of rows and the name of this group. Hence I have the following code:

```
np.random.seed(42)
y = np.random.randint(0,5,size=(100, 2))
df = pd.DataFrame(y, columns=list('AB'))
df.groupby('A').count().agg(['max','idxmax'])
```

The output of this:

```
        B
   max  28
idxmax  3
```

That is, group 3 has the maximum rows in it. The maxmimum is 28.

I would like the following output, with named aggregations:

```
Max  ID
28   3
```

My attempt at a solution:

```
np.random.seed(42)
y = np.random.randint(0,5,size=(100, 2))
df = pd.DataFrame(y, columns=list('AB'))
df.groupby('A').count().agg(Max=('B','max'), ID=('B','idxmax'))
```

Which throws the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-113-dcd54f9ab49e> in <module>
      2 y = np.random.randint(0,5,size=(100, 2))
      3 df = pd.DataFrame(y, columns=list('AB'))
----> 4 df.groupby('A').count().agg(Max=('B','max'),ID=('B','idxmax'))

TypeError: aggregate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'
```

If I remove the count() function, then the named aggregation seems to work. But of course, then it's not computing what I want to compute.

I would like to get this working, because my workaround looks quite messy:

```
np.random.seed(42)
y = np.random.randint(0,5,size=(100, 2))
df = pd.DataFrame(y, columns=list('AB'))
df.groupby('A').count().agg(['max','idxmax']).T.reset_index(drop=True).rename(columns={'max':'Max',
                                                                                       'idxmax':'ID'})
```

Output:

```
    Max ID
0   28  3
```

Pandas version 1.0.5.

Comment: Need as_index=False parameter - `df.groupby('A', as_index=False).count().agg(Max=('B','max'),ID=('B','idxmax')).T`

Comment: @Chris This throws the same error that I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [size()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) rather than [count()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) allows a small simplification:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
y = np.random.randint(0,5,size=(100, 2))
df = pd.DataFrame(y, columns=list('AB'))
df = df.groupby('A').size().agg(Max='max', ID='idxmax')
print(df)
```

Note that size() and count() are not identical. The size is the number of rows in each group. The count is the number of non-missing values in each column in each group. Accordingly, size() returns a Series rather than a DataFrame.

Of course, that means that after the aggregation, the output is also a Series rather than a DataFrame:

```
Max    28
ID      3
dtype: int64
```

...which you might or might not care about.

Comment: For me, I get the following error after running this: 
`---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-224-5ba549b5948f> in <module>
      2 y = np.random.randint(0,5,size=(100, 2))
      3 df = pd.DataFrame(y, columns=list('AB'))
----> 4 df = df.groupby('A').size().agg(Max='max', ID='idxmax')

TypeError: aggregate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'`

Comment: Weird - it works in Pandas v1.3.2. You could upgrade. Or if that's not an option, you could change the agg to `df = df.groupby('A').size().agg({'Max': 'max', 'ID': 'idxmax'})`, which I just tested in v1.0.5.

Comment: Performing an update of Pandas to 1.3.2 solved the problem